# Error al imprimir una matriz

Tags: java, array

Estoy creando una tabla para un programa de calificaciones, en este se pide ingresar el nombre de las materias (filas) y el nombre de los alumnos(columnas), al igual que se pide insertar las calificaciones correspondientes, estas ultimas estaran dentro de la matriz y se imprimen por pantalla; el error es que la salida a partir de la tercera posición imprime "de forma descordinada", acontinuación el código y la salida:

```
String arreglo[] = null;
    String nombres[] = null;
    double matriz[][] = null;
    int materias=0,alumnos=0;
    System.out.println("\n Bienvenido al programa calificaciones escolares :D ");
    System.out.println("\n Ingrese la cantidad de materias");
    materias = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
    arreglo = new String[materias];
    System.out.println("\n Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos");
    alumnos = Integer.parseInt(al.readLine());
    nombres = new String[alumnos];
//Llenamos las filas y columas en base a la cantidad de materias(filas) y alumnos(columnas)
    System.out.println("\n Creado la tabla :D");
    matriz = new double[materias][alumnos];
//Ingresamos las materias
    System.out.println("\n Ingrese el nombre de sus materias");
    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese una materia");
        arreglo[i] = al.readLine();
    }
 //Ingresamos el nombre de los alumnos      
    System.out.println("\n Ingrese los nombres de sus alumnos");
    for(int j=0;j<nombres.length;j++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre");
        nombres[j] = al.readLine();
    }
//Ingresamos las califiaciones de los alumnos
    System.out.println("\n Ingrese sus calificaciones");
    for(int fila=0;fila<matriz.length;fila++){
        for(int columna=0;columna<matriz.length;columna++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese una calificacion");
            matriz[fila][columna] = Double.parseDouble(al.readLine());
        }
    }
//mostramos las materias dentro del arreglo
    System.out.println("\t=====Tabla de calificaciones=====\t");
    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
        System.out.print("\t"+arreglo[i]+"\t");         
    }
//mostramos la matriz de calificaciones junto a los nombres de los alumnos
    for(int fila=0;fila<matriz.length;fila++){
        System.out.print("\n"+nombres[fila]+"\t");
        for(int columna=0;columna<matriz[fila].length;columna++){
            System.out.print(matriz[fila][columna]+"\t\t");
        }
    }
}
} //error al imprimir a partir de la tercera posición jejeje
```

Salida:

```
        =====Tabla de calificaciones=====
    Matematicas             Fisica          Astronomia
Juan    1.0             2.0             3.0
Manuel  4.0             5.0             6.0
Martinez        7.0             8.0             9.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que usando `printf` y un *flag* (por ejemplo `%14s`) se puede ir formateando la tabulación de los datos:

```
    //mostramos las materias dentro del arreglo
    System.out.println("\t=====Tabla de calificaciones=====\t");
    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
        //System.out.print("\t"+arreglo[i]+"\t");
        int sp=i>0?14:28;
        System.out.printf("%"+sp+"s",arreglo[i]);
    }

    //mostramos la matriz de calificaciones junto a los nombres de los alumnos
    for(int fila=0;fila<matriz.length;fila++){
        //System.out.print("\n"+nombres[fila]+"\t");
        System.out.printf("%n%-24s",nombres[fila]);
        int space=14;
        for(int columna=0;columna<matriz[fila].length;columna++){
            //System.out.print(matriz[fila][columna]+"\t\t");
            System.out.printf("%-"+space+"s",matriz[fila][columna]);
        }
    }
```

Eso imprime una salida como esta:

```
    =====Tabla de calificaciones=====
                 Matematicas        Fisica    Astronomia
Juan                    1.0           2.0           3.0
Manuel                  4.0           5.0           6.0
Martinez                7.0           8.0           9.0
```

Tambien en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000810/printing-with-t-tabs-does-not-result-in-aligned-columns) está planteado un problema bastante similar (*si acaso puede que sea el mismo*)

Comment: los valores de tipo enteros que ingresaste, refienren a un espacio que puede a ver entre los intervalos cierto?

Comment: Acá una descripción: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Format/0080__Java_Format_Flags.htm

Comment: gracias me a servido de mucha ayuda :D

Answer (score 0):

Cuando imprimes un "\t"  estas imprimiendo un tabular. Este tabular genera un espacio igual a un predeterminado número de caracteres vacios. Como la palabra "martinez" es muy larga respecto a los demas apellidos, este queda mas separado.

Una solucion simple sería igualar el largo los apellidos de los alumnos, recortando en el caso de los apellidos muy largos, o bien llenando con algun caracter de espacio u otro a los más cortos.